# Idiom/SWR "abrogate the raison d'etre"

Tags: single-word-requests

Example, some drunk in the final [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32485797/294884),

> ..the idea of "nesting" a promise would seem to *completely abrogate the raison d'etre* of promise.

("promise" is just a computing technique, a feature of the "java-script" computing milieu.)

Some commonish phrases come to mind, such as

> "defeat the whole purpose of..."

But, "raison d'etre" very perfectly references the, well, "raison d'etre" of some technology.  (Indeed "raison d'etre" is one of those phrases or words that is so absolutely perfect.)

I've got a feeling there is an equally precise SWR, or failing that a phrase, that nails the idea of "you did something that utterly missed, or utterly annulled, the entire raison d'etre of X"

(In software engineering, in particular, this is a common problem. So, you might look at your colleague's work and say *"you are so ####ing stupid that you don't even realise the whole entire reason to use XYZ is because of ABC, here you have actually been so thick you have used, I should say mangled, XYZ in such a way as to completely defeat that whole reason for XYZ existing"*...  again this is a commonplace in software, but it can happen in any field or in daily life.)

*abrogate the raison d'etre* is a beautifully precise phrase on the run, but is there a swr-idiom here?

Comment: Semantically, I can't see what's wrong with *defeat the [whole] purpose* - the only reason for preferring *abrogate the raison d'etre* might be that it gives you a chance to show off how eloquent you are with your multiligual powers of expression.

Comment: @Joe Blow, I don't really like the use of 'abrogate' here. I'm not sure why. I think it suggests that the thing doing the abrogating is doing it *intentionally*, which is not the case in this example. I think something like 'undermine' would be better.

Comment: the distinction between deliberately  / unknowingly is a great point, Silenus.  you made me think, "sabotage" can in fact be used here in certain cases.  now, **undermine** is a spectacular answer, click the damn answer button dude!

Answer (score 2):

Possibly ['nullify'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nullify?s=t)

> **verb** (used with object), nullified, nullifying.
>
> 1 to render or declare legally void or inoperative: 
>   to nullify a contract.
>
> 2 to deprive (something) of value or effectiveness; make futile or of no consequence.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

E.g. "...nesting a promise would seem to nullify it".

However, though accurate, using it in a technical programming context might introduce unnecessary confusion

Comment: superb suggestion ...

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the words **essence** or **substance**, but my only concern in using this word is that it might not fit the context (ie computing).

So probably, you might want to use the phrase **defeat its substance**

Answer (score 0):

Credit to **Silenus** for his/her comment.

You're looking for **"undermine"**   ......"would completely **[undermine](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=join+definition&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gfe_rd=cr&ei=uqvxVe72B8aB8Qf2vZ7gCw&gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=undermine+definition)** the raison..."

undermine - (verb) damage or weaken (someone or something), especially gradually or insidiously.

> - She tried to undermine my authority by complaining about me to my boss.
> - The events of the past year have undermined people's confidence in the government.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **render obsolete**.

- "obsolete" means no longer in general use, fallen into disuse.